# Beautiful Soup parent tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a tag with multiple children tags. When I find that tag, the children tags are also returned. How can I find only the parent tag?

```
<a id='id'>
    <b>text</b>
    <c>text</c>
</a>
```

should return only

```
<a id='id'></a>
```

or just

```
<a id='id'>
```

Comment: What would be the purpose of returning the parent tag without any of its children?

Comment: I want to examine the parent tag without looking into the children tags

Comment: What exactly do you intend to do with the parent tag? My guess is that you can do whatever it is you're trying to do, but you think the presence of the child tags (which are just representational) is preventing you from doing that.

Comment: Yes I want to search for a string that may be present in the children tags but I want to reject it if it is so.

Comment: @inyrface In that case, it sounds like the child tags would be important, no? Can you update your question with a specific example of your tags, what text you are trying to "reject", and what the desired output is? This smells like an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beautiful Soup will automatically pull the children from the parent tag but you can easily remove them by iterating through them like this:

```
s = soup.find('a', id='id')
for tag in s.findChildren():
   tag.decompose()
```